Is there a way to activate the printing header and footer using JS or CSS?

I've heard about @page in CSS, that can change margin, orientation, page break, but my question is: Is there a way to activate the "Headers and footers" option, for that when I open the printing window it already comes checked
I tried using the @page on css, but I don't know what attribute to use in this specific case

There is no way to check that option using CSS or JS in client side. (Though it is possible to use server side browser CLIs, that is probably not what you want.)
However, at least in Chrome when opening the Print interface you will notice the "Headers and footers" option will be hidden when the margin is none, or set to default and the default margin is 0.

vs

Hence, one workaround is to disable the default header and footer using @page {margin: 0;} which sets the default margin to 0. Then, just implement your own header and footer that simulates the printed header and footer: (Tested on Firefox, Chrome, Edge).
Note that this is still not perfect because:

Users can change the Margins to Custom and check the Headers and footers option.
Will break if the page is within an iframe.

If you can refactor your pages to move everything into a table, then the following works fine with multiple page printing.


window.addEventListener("beforeprint", (event) => {
  console.log(event)
  const printedTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
  document.getElementById("print-time").textContent = printedTime;
  document.getElementById("print-title").textContent = document.title;
  document.getElementById("print-url").innerHTML = window.location.href;
});
.print-only {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  @media print {
    display: revert;
  }
}

#print-title {
  float: right;
}

@page {
  margin: 0;
}
<table>
  <thead class="print-only print-header">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="print-time"></span>
        <span id="print-title"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Your actual content
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot class="print-only print-footer">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="print-url"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>



Else, without table, using display:fixed might not work well with multiple-page printing as the spaces won't be preserved for the headers/footers.


window.addEventListener("beforeprint", (event) => {
  document.getElementById("print-time").textContent = new Date().toLocaleString();
  document.getElementById("print-title").textContent = document.title;
  document.getElementById("print-url").textContent = window.location.href;
});
.print-only {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  margin: 0px 8px;
}
.print-footer {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.print-header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  #print-title {
    float: right;
  }
}

@page {
  margin: 0;
}

@media print {
  body {
    display: flow-root;
  }
  .contents {
    margin: 14px 0px;
  }
  .print-only {
    display: block;
  }
}
<div class="print-only print-header">
  <span id="print-time"></span>
  <span id="print-title"></span>
</div>
<div class="contents">Your original contents.
</div>
<div class="print-only print-footer">
  <span id="print-url"></span>
</div>



